# converting array from php 5.3 to php 4

Tags: php, arrays

hi i use this code in my wp site

```
function theme_files() {
   $scripts = [
    // ['handle' => 'date', 'src'=>'jquery.ui.datepicker-cc.all.min.js','dep'=> array( 'jquery' ),'var'=> false,'in_foot'=> true],
    ['handle' => 'date', 'src'=>'js-persian-cal.min.js','dep'=> array( 'jquery' ),'var'=> false,'in_foot'=> true],
    ['handle' => 'paralax', 'src'=>'jquery.fullpage.min.js','dep'=> array( 'jquery' ),'var'=> false,'in_foot'=> true],
    ['handle' => 'fullslud', 'src'=>'jquery.superslides.min.js','dep'=> array( 'jquery' ),'var'=> false,'in_foot'=> true],
    ['handle' => 'carousel', 'src'=>'owl-carousel.js','dep'=> array( 'jquery' ),'var'=> false,'in_foot'=> true],
    ['handle' => 'mmenu', 'src'=>'jquery.mmenu.min.all.js','dep'=> array( 'jquery' ),'var'=> false,'in_foot'=> true],
    ['handle' => 'lightbox', 'src'=>'lightbox.js','dep'=> array( 'jquery' ),'var'=> false,'in_foot'=> true],
    ['handle' => 'masonry', 'src'=>'masonry.pkgd.js','dep'=> array( 'jquery' ),'var'=> false,'in_foot'=> true],
    ['handle' => 'template', 'src'=>'theme.js','dep'=> array( 'jquery' ),'var'=> false,'in_foot'=> true],
    ['handle' => 'selectbox', 'src'=>'select2.min.js','dep'=> array( 'jquery' ),'var'=> false,'in_foot'=> true]
];


for ($i=0; $i < sizeof($scripts); $i++) {

    wp_enqueue_script( $scripts[$i]['handle'], get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/' . $scripts[$i]['src'], $scripts[$i]['dep'], $scripts[$i]['ver'] );    

}
}
```

but my customer migrate his website to a host with old version of php and i get syntax error

and i need to convert this array to old version.
can any one help me?

Comment: If they have PHP4.x I think the array sytax will be the least of your issues.   I recall fixing tons of PHP4 code back in the day when PHP5.3 came out.  Mostly constructors, `ereg()` and `split()`,  Ah the good old days.  I would seriously look at upgrading PHP...

Comment: FYI, short array syntax `[]` wasn't available until PHP5.4, if I recall.  You have `Array from PHP 5.3 to PHP 4`

Comment: This is gonna cause you some major grief   https://make.wordpress.org/core/2015/07/02/deprecating-php4-style-constructors-in-wordpress-4-3/  or not, I don't know.  lol

Answer (score 1):

Use from following structure:

```
$scripts = array(
     array('handle' => 'date', 'src'=>'js-persian-cal.min.js','dep'=> array( 'jquery' ),'var'=> false,'in_foot'=> true),
     array('handle' => 'paralax', 'src'=>'jquery.fullpage.min.js','dep'=> array( 'jquery' ),'var'=> false,'in_foot'=> true)
);
```

I had same issue and converted my arrays to old structure.

```
foreach($scripts as $script){
    wp_enqueue_script(  $script['handle'], get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/' .  $script['src'],  $script['dep'],  $script['ver'] );    
}
```

Comment: thank you but i got another error Undefined index: ver in  wp_enqueue_script( $scripts[$i]['handle'], get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/' . $scripts[$i]['src'], $scripts[$i]['dep'], $scripts[$i]['ver'] );

Comment: `var_dump( $scripts[$i] )` ...  check it's set etc.. etc.. but you are going to be chasing your tail trying to back port to PHP 4, i'm afraid.  What version of WP are you having.

Comment: I edited my answer, i tested this approach in the latest version of php(php 7)